# How to exit waitPress() fuction of the Keypad library?

Tags: arduino, interrupt-handling

I have a library on Arduino that declares a function like this :

```c
void Keypad::waitPress()
// Wait for any key to be pressed.
 { while (scan() == 0);
 }
```

Which, for one conditional is fine, but I also have an ISR (interrupt system routine) in my main code which will likely be triggered during the `waitPress()` call :

```c
static void isr_zero(void) {
    if (isr_change_flag == 0)
    {
      isr_dest = 0;
      isr_change_flag = 1;
    }
  }
```

Since `Keypad::waitPress` is a loop, it won't care if the ISR is triggered and will continue looping indefinitely until a key is pressed, which is an undesireable behaviour as I need that ISR to act there

Is there a way to break that `while` loop if the ISR is triggered?

- I can't modify a single line of the library
- `scan()` isn't a `public` function so I can't just rewrite `waitPress()` (which would have been the easiest)
- `goto` would have worked if it hadn't function-only scope

I thank about calling the processing function from the ISR, but I know that that's not good practice to hook a long running function within an ISR, although that would technically work

Comment: could you use another library or implement the functionalities yourself? A library that blocks the code like this without even a timeout seems to be very poorly written. This is not the wait you implement a wait for a key to be pressed.

Comment: I wish I could, but that's not a possibility, I need to work with that function, and indeed, it is written in a way that is giving me such a world of pain now. If only the scan function was public

Comment: Why is not a possibility? Is it a school assignment where you need to use that specific library? otherwise why would implementing a poorly coded functionality yourself not be an option?

Comment: If your ISR function is not working, it is something that didn't setup correctly, nothing to with the scan() loop.

Comment: @hcheung The ISR function is just fine, and works great, but the issue is that it will just land right back in the loop after running, as an ISR should do, I need to break that loop once the ISR has been triggered

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Not a school assignment, It's a proprietary component that requires that library in particular (`scan()` is way more involved than my pay-grade, likely would hit licensing issues if I were to paste that function in my code), if that had been a possibility I would have done it way earlier

Comment: you don't have to reimplement scan. Just the part of the library that says `while (scan() == 0)`  which is the one blocking the code. Whoever implemented it made a while that blocks the rest of the code.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki `scan()` is a private function, I can't reimplement that part without either modifying the library to declare it as public instead of private, or reimplement `scan()`, all of which are no-nos, library must be intact, and as I said, I can't reimplement `scan()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through the `.h` file, I found that the class actually exported a [functor](/questions/tagged/functor) that got me a view of the component output

I was able to implement it and my code now works

```cpp
while (KEYPAD1() != true) {
  if (isr_change_flag == 1)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
```